# Minimum value of $\sec(x)+\sec(y)$.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $x+y=2\alpha.$ Then minimum value of $\displaystyle \sec(x)+\sec(y)$, where $\displaystyle x,y\in\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$

What I try $\displaystyle \sec(x)+\sec(y)=\frac{\cos(x)+\cos(y)}{\cos(x)\cos(y)}$

$\displaystyle =2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})\cdot \frac{2}{\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)}$

$\displaystyle =2\cos(\alpha)\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})\cdot \frac{2}{\cos(2\alpha)+\cos(x-y)}$

Put $y=2\alpha-x,$ We get

$\displaystyle =\frac{4\cos(\alpha)\cdot \cos(x-\alpha)}{\cos(2\alpha)+\cos(2x-2\alpha)}$

How do I solve it after that , please have  look , Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rephrase the problem in the following way: you want to minimize the height of the midpoint of the line segement between $(x, \sec(x))$ and $(y, \sec(y))$ subject to the constraint $x, y \in (0, \pi/2)$, $x + y = 2\alpha$.

The secant function is convex on $(0, \pi/2)$---check its second derivative. This means that the height of the midpoint of this line segment will always be greater than $\sec((x + y)/2)$ unless $x = y$. It follows that the minimum is attained when $x = y$, i.e. at $x = y = \alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

If we apply the method of Lagrange multipliers to $f(x,y)=\sec x+\sec y$ with constraint $x+y-2\alpha=0$, we have
$$\sec x\tan x=\sec y\tan y=\lambda .$$
The function $h(x)=\sec x\tan x$ is increasing thus one-to-one on $(0,\frac\pi 2)$. Hence, $x=y=\alpha$ is the critical point.

It is minimum because when $x\to 2\alpha$, $f\to \sec2\alpha+1>2\sec\alpha$ for $2\alpha<\frac\pi 2$; when $x\to\frac\pi 2$, $f\to\infty$ for $2\alpha\geq\frac\pi 2$. Or we can apply a suitable second derivative test.